# C by K&R - for statement - "If expr_1 or expr_3 is omitted, it is simply dropped from the expansion"

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax

In section 3.5 "Loops - While and For" on page 60 in "The C Programming Language" 2nd by K&R, the authors said:

> The for statement
>
> ```
> for (expr_1; expr_2; expr_3)
>     statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> expr_1;
> while (expr_2) {
>     statement
>     expr_3;
> }
> ```
>
> except for the behavior of continue, which is described in section
>   3.7.
>
> Grammatically, the three components of a for loop are expressions.
>   Most commonly, expr_1 and expr_3 are assignments or function calls and
>   expr_2 is a relational expression. Any of the three parts can be
>   omitted, although the semicolons must remain. **If expr_1 or expr_3 is
>   omitted, it is simply dropped from the expansion.**

**So what do the authors mean by "If expr_1 or expr_3 is omitted, it is simply dropped from the expansion"? Which expansion do the authors mean?**

Comment: The "expansion" is the equivalent `while` statement.

Comment: I don't really see why he goes through the extra trouble of adding that last sentence; the expansion would work just fine even with `expr_1` and `expr_3` omitted (= empty) - you get two empty statements (a straight semicolon on its own), which are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 6):

When the authors say *expansion* they are referring to the `while` loop equivalent.

That is, if say `expr_1` and `expr_3` are omitted, the loop is equivalent to

```
while (expr_2) {
    statement 
}
```

Note that the text is a little out of date now, since from C99, you can declare variables in the `expr_1` part of the `for` loop without leaking those variables into the surrounding scope. The equivalent expansion is now not quite so simple.

Comment: Actually, nowadays it's just not possible to explain it with an expansion due to the idiotic rules for `for` variables scoping.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Indeed, it's not even a simple case of writing extra scope blocks.

Comment: Probably it's still worth keeping the not-really-it expansion adding a caveat about the corner case of adding a same-named variable in the inner scope, it's a useful teaching device anyway, even if slightly wrong.

Comment: @MatteoItalia How exactly is minimizing the scope of local variables as much as possible and thereby minimize namespace clutter and namespace-related bugs "idiotic"? It would seem that the vast majority of the C and C++ programmers in the world are of a different opinion.

Comment: I'm curious, @MatteoItalia: what displeases you so much about the scoping of variable declarations in the control clause of a `for` statement?

Comment: @Lundin. Absolutely. When I don't need to cut up bread, I say "this is the best thing since the introduction of variable declarations inside a `for`"

Comment: @Lundin: variables declaration in the `for` loop initialization clause is fantastic; what is stupid is that its scope is "magic" and not expressible as a `while` with an extra scope around, as it is injected in the inner scope, but the initialization happens "outside" of the loop (=at the first iteration). Obviously it's not something that causes problem in day to day usage, but complicates the wording in both the C and C++ standard and makes it more complicated than needed to explain formally how a `for` loop works.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: To me it represents an acceptable divergence of the two control structures `while` and `for`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't know, it's annoying to explain. You just finished explaining how `while` and scopes work, everything looks good and then comes `for` which would be explained easily with the transformation to `while`, but everything breaks down with the scope injection magic. It just *cannot* be expressed with the most "core" control structures - which is a shame, because it really helps to demystify `for` as a `while` in disguise.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Then you come to C++ and you get the foreach notation. Nice.

Comment: @Bathsheba: well, that's not really a problem, it's just a completely different construct straight from the syntax (which again can be explained easily with a simple transformation, *except* for the loop variable scoping. ARGH).

Answer (score 1):

Read the text once again, slowly.

The first form (`for` construct) is expanded into the second form (`while` construct). So, we can re-word the sentence like

> If  `expr_1` or `expr_3` is omitted (in the first form), it is simply dropped from the expansion (in the second form).